# Some xkb variants missing from Gnome Settings in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, keyboard-layout, gsettings, xkb

I've been trying to get the Swedish nodeadkeys layout to work on Ubuntu 22.04 (Wayland).

With X11 it's easy:

```bash
setxkbmap -variant nodeadkeys se
```

On Wayland however, this doesn't work.

Going to the Gnome Settings, *some* of the variants declared in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/se`, `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.list` do show up in the list of input sources. For example, `German (no dead keys)` is there. However, `Swedish (nodeadkeys)` is not.

Toggling extended input sources in `gnome-tweaks` or `dconf-editor` under `/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/show-all-sources` does not help.

Where can I set these variants in Gnome Settings? Why are some variants hidden?

Answer (score 0):

An input source can be selected even though it is missing from the gnome settings UI.

List available layouts, then variants:

```
localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts
# in my case, "se"
localectl list-x11-keymap-variants se
```

Get current setting

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
```

To use a variant, concatenate the layout and variant with `+`, e.g. `se+nodeadkeys`, then update the input source with gsettings:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'se+nodeadkeys')]"
```